# Parse array output into table -- Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

I am integrating someone else's library in Ruby/Rails that provides custom class which returns output from an API. This is an example of the code and output that comes when the class and custom method is submitted in the rails console:

```
CustomClass.mymethod 'this is a normal string of text that i am submitting to the rails console.'

=> #<CustomClass::MyMethod:0x10159d4e8 @info={"output1"=>"15", "output2"=>"1"}, @otherinfo={0}, @moreinfo={0}, @stillmore={"violations"=>"0"}>
```

In my application, I call this on a user-submitted text post (called "content") & put the output into a column associated with that post in the "posts" table. Right now this is being done within the "create" action in my posts controller:

```
@post.output = CustomClass.mymethod(@post.content)
```

Which posts the right output, but its formatting is a mess:

--- !ruby/object:CustomClass::MyMethod otherinfo: {} moreinfo: {} info: ? !ruby/string:REXMLUtiliyNodeString str: output1 attributes: {} : !ruby/string:REXMLUtiliyNodeString str: '1' attributes: {} ? !ruby/string:REXMLUtiliyNodeString str: output2 attributes: {} : !ruby/string:REXMLUtiliyNodeString str: '15' attributes: {} stillmore: {0}

Is there an easy way to clean up the output and write each piece into different columns of my posts table, or can I grab just one of the array objects (@otherinfo / otherinfo: {}) and write it into the posts table?

I am pretty new to Ruby/Rails so I appreciate your patience and help! I am sure this is something simple but I couldn't find anything today that got me where I needed to be. I'll even appreciate links that will help me understand how to learn the right commands to do the parsing or conversion of the text string.

Thanks!

Comment: What input produced that output?

Comment: Sorry--I hadn't indented the output string properly so some was being cut off...have now fixed the display formatting to show the whole output.

Comment: The output you're receiving back is YAML, but it's malformed. Your best bet is to figure out why it's malformed then parse it using the YAML interpreter to turn it back into a Ruby object. As is, it's creating a custom class called MyMethod, with some fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my own question:

I am so new that I was trying to write a ruby object directly into the table, which only takes text. I looked around and found out how to pull fields out of the hash, so now I just do this in the create action of my post controller:

```
file = Yomu.new params[:post][:file]
@post.output = file.text
info = Customclass.stats(@post.output)
@post.field1= info.method1['count']
@post.field2= info.method2['count']
@post.field3 = info.method3['count']
```

Anyway, lesson being, make sure you know what you're working with first.

Answer (score 0):

The messy answer looks almost like a hash. I'd use a regular expression to reduce each "? !ruby/string:REXMLUtiliyNodeString str: output1 attributes: {} : !ruby/string:REXMLUtiliyNodeString str: '1' attributes: {} ?"

Something like this:

```
def clean(string)
  str.gsub(/\?.*?REXML.*?\?/){|data|m=/.*odeString str: (\S*).*odeString str: ('.*?').*/.match(data); "{ #{m[1]}: #{m[2]} }"}
end
```

This will replace the above substring, question marks and all, with "{ output1: '1' }"

Then you can just eval the whole string as a hash expression.

This is a little bit brittle, but may work for you.

Comment: The output is YAML, and is malformed, and should be parsed by a YAML interpreter. It's generating a custom class.

Comment: I am working with this answer (right now the YAML interpreter stuff is above my abilities). I put the regular expression as a private function in my controller and then call it by clean(@post.output) but am getting the following error:   undefined local variable or method `str' for #<PostsController:0x41e3200> --- do I need to change something within the clean method, or place it somewhere else?